# Pandas: Replace column values with blanks inside a function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

I need to capture the first value in a column based on it's position, then replace all values with blanks. A DataFrame is passed to a function which then uses `enumerate` to go through the columns:

DF:

```
field1    field2    dropdown
-----------------------------------------
23423     hello     this\nis\na\ndropdown
23424     world     this\nis\na\ndropdown
```

Function:

```
def create_worksheet(df_input, filename)
    for col_num, value in enumerate(df_input.columns.values):
        if df_input.columns.get_loc(value) > 1:
            dropdown = df_input[value].iloc[0].split("\n")
            df_input[value].replace('^.*$','',regex=True,inplace=True)
            worksheet.set_column(col_num, col_num, 15, column_format_light_yellow)
            worksheet.data_validation(1, col_num, df_input.shape[0], col_num, 
                                     {'validate': 'list','source': dropdown})
```

**The `replace` doesn't work.**

Why isn't the replace working? No errors are occurring. But the values remain in the column. They should be blank.

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataframe with sample output. It would be easier to see what data you have and what you're looking to get with the replace call.

Comment: @HenryEcker I added a DF that mimics the format. I need to create a dropdown from any value in the last column -- then delete all values. The value's only purpose is to temporarily hold the dropdown values.

Answer (score 1):

To address the replace issue I believe you are missing the `regex` statement which by default is set to False.

```
df_input['value'].replace('^.*$','',regex=True,inplace=True)
```

EDIT: Given your comment and the data you added in your code as well as the edit (you added the `regex=True` in your code) , if your dataset has only 3 columns and you state this condition `df_input.columns.get_loc(value) > 9` it will always evaluate to False because number of columns < 9.

Comment: Tried that. Values still remain.

Comment: Thanks, please check my edit.

Comment: Even when I switch that number to less than the number of columns it doesn't remove the values.